# I am looking for ways I can simplify a series of subs to minimize repeated code

Tags: vb.net

I have a series of snips that I have more than 50 of, but they aren't that different.  Is there a simpler or less line consuming version of this?  code below (which I have a total of 60 of these...scenarios):  They are invisible buttons FYI that they click...  yeah.. I know.
the data pulled is used for varying reasons.  Thank you, and sorry.

```
Private Sub Alabama_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Alabama.Click
    SelectedStateOverviewLabel.Text = "Alabama"
    StateTwoDigit.Text = "AL"
    StateInitials = "AL"
    Call StateClick()
End Sub 'Alabama
Private Sub Alaska_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Alaska.Click
    SelectedStateOverviewLabel.Text = "Alaska"
    StateTwoDigit.Text = "AK"
    StateInitials = "AK"
    Call StateClick()
End Sub 'Alaska
Private Sub Arizona_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Arizona.Click
    SelectedStateOverviewLabel.Text = "Arizona"
    StateTwoDigit.Text = "AZ"
    StateInitials = "AZ"
    Call StateClick()
End Sub 'Arizona
```

Comment: create a method for common code and call it from all the events

Comment: are you using a database ? and if you say the buttons are invisible , how dos it get clicked ?

Comment: it takes those values and runs against a database, and also changing various variables in the application. they can still be clicked, and it is like a map clicking, bit off a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for common code you should create a common routine and pass in parameters:

```
Private Sub UpdateState(stateName as string, stateCode as string)
    SelectedStateOverviewLabel.Text = stateName
    StateTwoDigit.Text = stateCode
    StateInitials = stateCode
End Sub
```

Then you can call this routine as follows:

```
Private Sub Alabama_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Alabama.Click
    UpdateState("Alabama","AL")
    StateClick()
End Sub 'Alabama
Private Sub Alaska_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Alaska.Click
    UpdateState("Alaska","AK")
    StateClick()
End Sub 'Alaska
Private Sub Arizona_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Arizona.Click
    UpdateState("Arizona","AZ")
    StateClick()
End Sub 'Arizona
```

However you should probably think about storing your states in a HashTable and having an Enum for the name, but that is out of scope of this question